# How to move cookies from one page to another in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I am dealing with a PHP site that use cookies to login users; the problem is I can't get the input email from the login page to the home page.

I always get this in the home page:

> (Welcome Email!)

where it should be:

> (Welcome user@gmail.com!)

Here is my code of the home page:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["Email"])){

  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["Email"]. "!<br>";
  echo '<a href="logoutForm.php">logout</a>';  
}
else{
setcookie("Email", "Email", time()-50000);
echo 'you are logged out please <a href="log_in.php">login</a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: It may have something to do with WHEN you are setting your cookie.  PHP runs on the server, and sends the cookie info along with the header information.  So it has to be sent before any other part of any script is run.

Comment: Your cookie has an expiry before the current time, so it will die as soon as it is delivered. Why the `-50000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show us the code on your login page so that we know how you are setting  your "Email" cookie variable, like did you use

```
    setcookie("Email", "bla_blah_blah");
```

Comment: here its: $expire=time()+30;
setcookie("Email", "Email", $expire);

Comment: Oops! You got served!. You set the value of your "Email" cookie to "Email" so on your home page you get <b>Welcome Email!)</b> too! You should rather do something like `setcookie("Email", $_POST['email'] )`... Got it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using sessions instead?

After successful login, before redirect:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Email']="user@gmail.com";
```

Then on your welcome page:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION["Email"])){
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["Email"]. "!<br>";
    echo '<a href="logoutForm.php">logout</a>';  
 }
 else{
    setcookie("Email", "Email", time()-50000);
    echo 'you are logged out please <a href="log_in.php">login</a>'; 
 }

?>
```

This also has the added benefit of storing the session info on your server as opposed to on the user's computer.

To kill the session just use:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: it works with session, but is it possible to work with cookies